# Undertow in new WildFly and PrimeFaces - EJB - Hibernate in a non-blocking I/O way?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, nonblocking, wildfly

I read that new version of WildFly contains Undertow web server that allows to use a non-blocking I/O operations.

I checked examples provided by undertow.io site. But I would like to ask if it is possible to intergrate this technique/pattern into EJB . My project structure is very similar to Kitchensink example provided by JBoss.

So my question is if there are some examples of implementing non-blocking I/O with EJB or it happens automatically in new WildFly 8 ?